# Select the maximum for each value in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with a list of STATEs and ORDERAMOUNTs:

```
State | OrderAmount
===================
New York  5
New York  6
Pennsylvania  6
Pennsylvania  7
```

I want to select a list of all states that have any single order LARGER then a given amount, say 15, as well as the largest order amount for that state. How would I iterate through all STtate values to get this list using a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but the following should work:

```
SELECT state, max(orderamount) AS amount FROM table GROUP BY state HAVING amount > 15;
```

Comment: @Umer: Agreed, however this type of query on large tables can be painful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Select s1.state, s1.orderamount, MAX(s2.orderamount) AS max_amount FROM states s1 
LEFT JOIN states s2 ON s1.id = s2.id
WHERE s1.orderamount > 15 GROUP BY s1.id
```